# how to call a templetized vector of records

Tags: c++, templates, stl, c++11

I'm having a problem getting the syntax right so if someone can help,please?
I have a timing function which take a function and its arguments as a parameters, but I'm not sure how should the call look like.

```
#include <iostream>
#include <iterator>
#include <random>
#include <vector>
#include<list>
#include<deque>
#include <algorithm>
#include <chrono>
#include <functional>
#include <sstream>

using namespace std;
using namespace std::chrono;


int global_SortType = 1;

template<class F, class A, typename T>
void times(F func, A arg, int n, T typeval)    // call func(arg,n)
{
    auto t1 = system_clock::now();
    func(arg, n, typeval);
    auto t2 = system_clock::now();
    auto dms = duration_cast<milliseconds>(t2-t1);
    cout << "f(x) took " << dms.count() << " milliseconds\n";
}

template<class T>
bool Greater(const T& v1, const T& v2)
{
    return false;
}

bool Greater(const int& v1, const int& v2)
{
    return v1 > v2;
}

bool Greater(const string& v1, const string& v2)
{
    return strcmp(v1.c_str(), v2.c_str()) > 0;
}

template <class T>
struct GreaterThan: public std::binary_function<T, T, bool > {
    bool operator () ( const T &ival, const T &newval ) const {
        return Greater(ival,  newval);
    }
};

string random_gen(string& s)
{
    string Result;          // string which will contain the result
    ostringstream convert;   // stream used for the conversion
    convert << rand();
    return convert.str();
}

int random_gen(int& i){
    default_random_engine re { std::random_device()() };
     uniform_int_distribution<int> dist;
     auto r= bind(dist,re);
     int x =r();
     return x;

}

template<class T>
void print(T& val)
{
}

void print(int& val)
{
    cout << val << " ";
}

void print(string& val)
{
    cout << val.c_str() << " ";
}

struct Record
{
    int v;
    string s;

    Record(){}
    Record(int iv, string ss): v(iv), s(ss)
    {
    }
};

Record random_gen(Record& r)
{
    string stemp;
    int i = 0;
    return Record(random_gen(i), random_gen(stemp));
}

void print(Record& r)
{
    cout<<"int="<<r.v<<" string=";
    print(r.s);
}

bool Greater(const Record& r1, const Record& r2)
{
    return global_SortType == 1 ? Greater(r1.v, r2.v) : Greater(r1.s, r2.s);
}

template<typename SequenceContainer, class T>
void build_cont(SequenceContainer& seq, int n, T valtype)
{
    for(int i=0; i!=n; ++i) {
        T gen = random_gen(valtype);
        typename SequenceContainer::const_iterator it;
        it=find_if(seq.begin(), seq.end(), std::bind2nd(GreaterThan<T>(), gen));
        seq.insert(it, gen);
    }
    for(int i=n-1; i >=0; i--)
    {
        int gen = i;
        if(i > 0)
            gen = random_gen(i)%i;
        typename SequenceContainer::const_iterator it=seq.begin();
        for(int j = 0; j < gen; j++)
            it++;
        seq.erase(it);

                }
            }

int main()
{
int n=1000;
vector<int> v;
times(build_cont<std::vector<int>, int>, v, n, 0); // works

vector<string> sv;
string stemp = "";

times(build_cont<std::vector<string>, string>, sv, n, stemp); // works

    global_SortType = 1;
    vector<Record> rv;
    Record rtemp(0, "sfds");

    global_SortType = 2;
    vector<Record> rsv;
    Record rstemp(0, "sfds");

    //This one desn't work and I'm not sure of the right syntax

    times(build_cont<std::vector<Record>,Record>, sv, n, stemp); 

    return 0;
}
```

I'm getting this error
 Non-const lvalue reference to type 'vector>' cannot bind to a value of unrelated type 'vector, allocator>>'

and it points to line

```
func(arg, n, typeval);
```

Comment: If you are seeing compiler errors, include (copy and paste) the first dozen or so.

Comment: I'm getting one error

Comment: Non-const lvalue reference to type 'vector<struct Record, allocator<struct Record>>' cannot bind to a value of unrelated type 'vector<class std::__1::basic_string<char>, allocator<class std::__1::basic_string<char>>>'

Comment: and it points to this line `func(arg, n, typeval);`

Comment: So why wont't you include its full text in your question?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Inside this function:

```
template<typename SequenceContainer, class T>
void build_cont(SequenceContainer& seq, int n, T valtype)
```

You are using `const_iterator`s rather than `iterator`s to perform insertions and removals. You should change the definition of that function as follows:

```
template<typename SequenceContainer, class T>
void build_cont(SequenceContainer& seq, int n, T valtype)
{
    for(int i=0; i!=n; ++i) {
        T gen = random_gen(valtype);
        typename SequenceContainer::iterator it;
        //                          ^^^^^^^^ 

        it=find_if(seq.begin(), seq.end(), std::bind2nd(GreaterThan<T>(), gen));
        seq.insert(it, gen);
    }
    for(int i=n-1; i >=0; i--)
    {
        int gen = i;
        if(i > 0)
            gen = random_gen(i)%i;
            typename SequenceContainer::iterator it=seq.begin();
            //                          ^^^^^^^^ 

        for(int j = 0; j < gen; j++)
            it++;
        seq.erase(it);
    }
}
```

Also, you forgot to `#include` the `<cstring>` standard header, which contains the definition for the `strcmp()` function. You are using that function inside your `Greater()` function:

```
bool Greater(const string& v1, const string& v2)
{
    return strcmp(v1.c_str(), v2.c_str()) > 0;
    //     ^^^^^^
    //     You need to #include <cstring> before calling this function
}
```

Moreover, you're invoking function `times()` with the wrong arguments (`sv` and `stemp`):

```
//This one desn't work and I'm not sure of the right sytax
times(build_cont<std::vector<Record>,Record>, rsv, n, rstemp);
//                                            ^^^     ^^^^^^
```

Comment: @user1653150: Updated the answer to include the fix to the last error